# Error running NPM on ubuntu server (digital ocean)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I've installed node (nodejs) and it appears to work correctly, however when using NPM in any way I get an error.  I have googled the error extensively and tried various solutions but am unable to find a solution.

In terminal I get:

```
dan@resume:~$ nodejs -v
v6.9.1
dan@resume:~$ npm -v
/usr/local/bin/node: 1: /usr/local/bin/node: ??????: not found
/usr/local/bin/node: 2: /usr/local/bin/node: -í: not found
/usr/local/bin/node: 3: /usr/local/bin/node:?__stubs__TEXT.ͭ8=?__stub_helper__TEXTh: not found
/usr/local/bin/node: 4: /usr/local/bin/node: ?ph: not found
/usr/local/bin/node: 6: /usr/local/bin/node: ??__cstring__TEXT??KV
                                                              ?__const__TEXTp?$?Gp?
                                                                                    __ustring__TEXT0@
0__dof_node__TEXTp,p,__unwind_info__TEXT5?,5__eh_frame__TEXT?aP??ah__DATA?: not found
/usr/local/bin/node: 7: /usr/local/bin/node: ?: not found
/usr/local/bin/node: 8: /usr/local/bin/node: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
dan@resume:~$
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is specific to Ubuntu post it at http://askubuntu.com/, there you may get answer

Comment: Did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876831/error-running-npm-on-ubuntu-server-digital-ocean/40876935#40876935) help? Any comments?

Comment: I could not follow the answer you gave rsp (my fault).  I got frustrated and redid the droplet entirely and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how did you install it that the binary name is nodejs instead of node.

See [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a) on how to install Node on any Linux/Unix system - this is not specific to Ubuntu.

The current Node version is 7.2.0.